# Make DataTable ignore Child rows when counting number of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable and I have added child rows that get toggled when a parent row is clicked using the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr.parent')
        .css("cursor","pointer")
        .attr("title","Click to expand/collapse")
        .click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle();
        });
    $('tr[class^=child-]').hide().children('td');
});
```

Basically, on my table I do the following:

1. Put a class of "parent" on each parent row (tr)
2. Give each parent row (tr) an id
3. Give each child row a class of "child-ID" where ID is the id of the
   parent tr that it belongs to

This works perfectly, meaning that child rows will only be shown when the corresponding parent row is clicked, however, if for example, I have 8 parent rows and one of the rows has 2 child rows, the data table will show "Showing 10 rows", what I would like is basically to ignore the child rows when computing the number of rows, number of rows remaining, etc...

Is there a clean way to do this **without** having to modify the original datatable js?

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/xv3xjbLL/1/

In the JsFiddle, if the first row is clicked, two child rows will apear, however the counter shows 10 while only 8 are displayed initially. Is there a way not to count the child rows?

Comment: `if for example, I have 8 parent rows and one of the rows has 2 child rows, the data table will show "Showing 10 rows"`, no this is not happening here:- https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html   .So either create a fiddle of your code so that we can check and let you know. Or take a reference from the example and correct your code

Comment: @AlivetoDie , added JsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Please find in this link for your solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      'iDisplayLength': 12,
      "aLengthMenu": [[12, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    });
});

$(function() {
 $('tr.parent')
  .css("cursor","pointer")
  .attr("title","Click to expand/collapse")
  .click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle();
  });
 $('tr[class^=child-]').hide().children('td');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" hfre="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
       
       
       

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1" class="parent">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td> 4</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-1">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-1">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td>5.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 6</td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
            <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
            <td>Win XP</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="parent" id="2">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-2">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-2">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>1.9</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
            <td>OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
            <td>OSX.3+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.2</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.4</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
            <td>Gnome</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.2</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td>125.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.3</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td>312.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 2.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>419.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 3.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>522.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>420</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
            <td>iPod</td>
            <td>420.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>413</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.2</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.5</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera for Wii</td>
            <td>Wii</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nokia N800</td>
            <td>N800</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS</td>
            <td>8.5</td>
            <td>C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
            <td>KDE 3.1</td>
            <td>3.1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
            <td>KDE 3.3</td>
            <td>3.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
            <td>KDE 3.5</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Links</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Lynx</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>IE Mobile</td>
            <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>PSP browser</td>
            <td>PSP</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other browsers</td>
            <td>All others</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Venkatachalam_Perisetla/xv3xjbLL/2/

Comment: Unfortunately, this covers only the case where there two child rows, things is that maybe all of these parent rows will have child rows, or that none of them will have child rows, etc... This seems to cover only the case where there are 2 child rows. Am I wrong?

Comment: whenever child row will come automatically it will ignore that only parent row will show as  a count right?

Comment: yes, that's the goal. So basically, if the table is supposed to show 10 rows per page and that there are 14 rows (10 parents, 4 childs), it should show 10 rows and show that it is showing 10 rows and the total number of rows at the bottom should also only take parents into account.

Comment: Peter, can u append that child after datatable will load then it will work, while load time you are passing that child tr also that'swhy it will take total count.

Comment: That could be a way of doing it, I will try it out by end of week and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: If you want any help, i will help you on that don't worry. pvchalam18@gmail.com it is my skype and mail if u have any doubt ping me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143242/discussion-between-venkatachalam-and-peter).